# cannot install history.js using npm

Tags: ubuntu, npm, history.js

)
I cannot install **history.js** using npm on Ubuntu 15.10.

node v5.0.0

npm  v3.5.3

Log:

```
 sudo npm i history

 > history@1.17.0 postinstall /media/programs/WEB/Projects/React/Redux/node_modules/history
 > node ./npm-scripts/postinstall.js

 module.js:339
     throw err;
     ^

 Error: Cannot find module '/media/programs/WEB/Projects/React/Redux/node_modules/history/npm-scripts/postinstall.js'
     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15)
     at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25)
     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:457:10)
     at startup (node.js:136:18)
     at node.js:972:3
 npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
 npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.6
 npm ERR! Linux 4.2.0-22-generic
 npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "i" "history"
 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
 npm ERR! history@1.17.0 postinstall: `node ./npm-scripts/postinstall.js`
 npm ERR! Exit status 1
 npm ERR! Failed at the history@1.17.0 postinstall script 'node ./npm-scripts/postinstall.js'.
 npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
 npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the history package,
 npm ERR! not with npm itself.
 npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
 npm ERR!     node ./npm-scripts/postinstall.js
```

Do you have any idea?

P.S Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old problem some packages don't support on some os. The same problem was occurring with fsevents@1.0.6 before npm 3.3.12 but it had fixed in 3.3.12.

Now in npm 3.5.3, it is again creating issues so you can wait for next build of npm.

You can read about this [here](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10768)